# How to avoid downloading gradle dependencies each time react-native project is build?

Tags: android, react-native

I am working on a react-native android project. For which I am using "react-native run-android" command to build and execute the android project.

But each time I use above command, the react-native system downloads the gradle component while it's already installed in my system. Had cross checked that the installed version is same as that which is about to get install via react-native-cli.

Would like to know is there a way by which the existing downloaded gradle can be used rather than downloading it?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: UPDATE: I checked in the gradle.wrapper properties the version of gradle is 2.14.1-all. Acc. to the path set in zipStorePath, this gradle should be present in C:\user\.gradle\wrapper\dists. In my case, its present over there. Still the system is trying to download fresh copy of it rather than using cached copy. Can anyone please suggest why is it so?

Answer (score 5):

You can use **'react-native start'** instead of **'react-native run-android'** after building the debug apk.It will start the server without downloading the gradlew properties.